# How to decipher these 2 lines of code? What does it mean?

Tags: python, pytorch, generative-adversarial-network

This is the code:

```
real_idx = torch.rand(len(real)) > 0.2
real_selected = real[real_idx][: int(len(real)*p_real)]
```

p_real is actually 0.2

We're supposed to mix 2 tensors, namely the real and the fake tensor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first line creates a random mask the size of `real`. The second line applies this mask on `real` and slices out 20% the size of `real` from whatever the masking operation returned.

Now if what you meant to ask was why is this being done, then you'd have to give more details.